# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' in my line of python code

Tags: python

I am currently trying to run someone else code on my data and they don't have any annotations of each line of code is doing. Here is the line of code i am running

```
grouped = data.groupby(lambda x: re.match("[A-Z]+[0-9]+", x).group(), axis=1)
```

Here is the dataframe that i am using with the above code

```
     WWA25 WWA25replicate WWA26 WWA27 WWA28 WWA30
rs
TP12     T              T     T     T     T     N
TP14     N              N     N     N     N     N
TP15     N              N     N     N     N     N
TP16     N              N     N     N     N     N
TP18     T              T     N     N     N     T
```

And here is the error..

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I understand the error that it is trying to do a regular expression search and it cannot find anything and so the result is `none`

But what exactly does the code trying to do?

Comment: Are you running this in Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: The pattern being searched for is one or more capital letters followed by one or more digits.  You haven't posted enough code to tell anything beyond that.

Comment: are you using `dataFrame.groupby` a feature of the pandas library? Consider adding more context to your question to avoid speculation.